# How to run selinux sanbdox with access to /dev/urandom

Tags: selinux

I'm trying to run my application inside an SELinux sandbox.
My application needs access to /dev/urandom, and the default sandbox policy does not allow that.

What is a simple method to allow my sandbox context access to /dev/urandom?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get this "SELinux sandbox"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a simple method to allow my sandbox context access to /dev/urandom?

Any of the following, though the first is ideal.

- Change your policy
- Change the context of /dev/urandom
- Change the context of your process
- `mknod` a new `/dev/urandom` with  different name and appropriate context. Point your application at that.

Comment: right now I have my process running in the default sandbox_t context. Can I modify the policy to allow access to my process, but not to other sandboxed processes?

Comment: No, you'll have to copy the sandbox_t to another context name, bless the context to read `/dev/urandom`, and run your program in that new context.